# function inside a function, how to exit out of main function

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i am ina function which was called from inside another function, how do I exit out of the main/parent function?

e.g:

```
function(firstFunction(){
    //stuff
    secondFunction()
    // stuff if second function doesnt exit
}

function secondFunction(){
    if( // some stuff here to do checks...){
        /***** Exit from this and firstFunction, i.e stop code after this function call from running ****/
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't, without a little bit of workaround. There's no direct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return some value to indicate that you want to exit from the `firstFunction()`.

e.g.

```
function(firstFunction(){
    //stuff
    rt = secondFunction()
    if (rt == false) {
        return; // exit out of function
    }
    // stuff if second function doesnt exit
}

function secondFunction(){
    if( // some stuff here to do checks...){
        /***** Exit from this and firstFunction, i.e stop code after this function call from running ****/
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is a decent way.

Comment: Note that without a `return true` in the `secondFunction`, `undefined` will be returned, which means `!rt` will always be true, and the `firstFunction` will always exit.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are obviously correct, but I'd differ slightly and do it this way...

```
function firstFunction() {
    if (secondFunction()) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}

function secondFunction() {
    if (something) {
        return false;  // exit from here and do not continue execution of firstFunction
    }
    return true;
}
```

It's just a difference of opinion in coding styles really, and will have no difference to the end result.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly return control flow 2-steps up the stack. However you could return a value from your inner function which is then handled in the outer. Something like this:

```
function(firstFunction(){
    var result = secondFunction()
    if (!result) 
        return
}

function secondFunction(){
    if( /* some stuff here to do checks */ ){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do a callback like this:

```
function firstFunction () {
  secondFunction(function () {
    // do stuff here if secondFunction is successfull
  });
};

function secondFunction (cb) {
  if (something) cb();
};
```

this way you can do asyncronous stuff in secondFunction too like ajax etc.

Comment: +1 for an alternative method.  I can't think of why I'd ever use it, but I like it :D